# Virtuemart component firstname,lastname in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, virtuemart

firstname, lastname is getting stored into dataabase.  They are entering into the db, but values are not being stored properly. When retrived, it is showing like firstname,lastname as the output. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what the problem is?

Comment: After registering in the site, registered user getting mail like the following way, Hello First Name Last Name, here is the activation link.

Comment: Have you changed any of the virtumart code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've made no code changes, there's no reason that they're not being stored properly.

To change how they appear to the users, you'll need to review/edit the various places they're being used.

1. Is the newly created user account maintenance displaying/updating correctly?
2. The emails that go out are in templates (locations depend on what version you're using)  so find them, and adjust to your liking.